# How to auto ok when use camera of android?

Tags: android, image, camera, save

I have a problem, it is i using camera of android with call MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    filepath = getOutputMediaFile();
    uri = Uri.fromFile(filepath);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
```

When i capture and then it don't auto save, i must be click to buttom save or buttom not, while i just need to save.

[Button save and button not](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fiiFznRZE2ZmIybkVVNm52VVE/view)

This not comfortable, so how to set auto save and pretermit this step?

Answer (score 0):

That's a function of the camera app. You would have to wrote your own code for capturing an image with the camera.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, i think i know the reason, and i have chosen different way :)